# syntax error at or near "VARCHAR" LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATEADD (interval VARCHAR(4000),

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-12

please help me  to solve this error
following is my code and after below my code error also written

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATEADD (interval VARCHAR(4000), adding INT, entry_date TIMESTAMP(0))  
  RETURN TIMESTAMP(0) as 
$body$ 
declare 
  result TIMESTAMP(0); 
BEGIN 
   If (UPPER(interval) = 'D') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'Y') OR (UPPER(interval) ='W') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'DD') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'DDD') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'DAY')  THEN result := entry_date + adding; ELSIF (UPPER(interval) = 'WW') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'IW')  OR (UPPER(interval) = 'WEEK') THEN result := entry_date + (adding * 7); ELSIF  (UPPER(interval) = 'YYYY') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'YEAR') THEN result := add_months(entry_date,adding * 12); ELSIF (UPPER(interval) = 'Q') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'QUARTER') 
     THEN result := add_months(entry_date,adding * 3); 
   ELSIF(UPPER(interval)= 'M') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'MM') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'MONTH') THEN 
     result :=add_months(entry_date,adding); 
   ELSIF  (UPPER(interval) = 'H') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'HH') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'HOUR') THEN 
     result := entry_date+ (adding /24); 
   ELSIF  (UPPER(interval) = 'N') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'MI') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'MINUTE') THEN 
      result := entry_date+ (adding /24/60); 
   ELSIF  (UPPER(interval) = 'S') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'SS') OR (UPPER(interval) = 'SECOND') THEN 
      result := entry_date + (adding /24/60/60); 
   END IF; 
   RETURN result; 
exception when others then 
   raise_application_error('-20000',sqlerrm); 
end; 
$body$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VARCHAR"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATEADD (interval VARCHAR(4000), ...

Comment: So much code to avoid writing `timestamp + interval '...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interval` is a reserved keyword (a data type), you need to either use double quotes `"interval"` or find a different name, e.g. you can use `add_interval` instead.

You can add a number to a `timestamp` in Postgres. You need to construct an `interval` from the passed value. The easiest way is to use `make_interval()` for that.

In PL/pgSQL it's `returns XXX` not `return XXX`.

You also need to replace `raise_application_error('-20000',sqlerrm)` with something else. But I don't see any benefit in obfuscating the original error, so my recommendation would be to simply remove the exception handler completely.

You can also simplify your IF conditions by using `IN` instead of multiple `OR` expressions.

So you wind up with something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATEADD (add_type text, adding INT, entry_date TIMESTAMP(0))  
  RETURNS TIMESTAMP(0) as 
$body$ 
declare 
  result TIMESTAMP(0); 
BEGIN 
   If upper(add_type) IN ('D','Y','W','DD','DDD','DAY') THEN 
     result := entry_date + make_interval(days => adding); 
   ELSIF upper(add_type) IN ('WW', 'IW', 'WEEK') THEN 
     result := entry_date + make_interval(weeks => adding); 
   ELSIF  upper(add_type) IN ('YYYY', 'YEAR') THEN 
     result := add_months(entry_date, adding * 12); 
   ELSIF upper(add_type) IN ('Q', 'QUARTER') THEN  
     result := add_months(entry_date, adding * 3); 
   ELSIF upper(add_type) IN ('M', 'MM', 'MONTH') THEN 
     result := add_months(entry_date, adding); 
   ELSIF upper(add_type) IN ('H', 'HH', 'HOUR') THEN 
     result := entry_date + make_interval(hours => adding); 
   ELSIF upper(add_type) IN ('N', 'MI', 'MINUTE') THEN 
      result := entry_date + make_interval(minutes => adding);
   ELSIF upper(add_type) IN ('S', 'SS', 'SECOND') THEN 
      result := entry_date + make_interval(secs => adding); 
   END IF; 
   RETURN result; 
end; 
$body$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: It work. Thank you so much for your suggestion. but how can i use exception clause in this code

Comment: You would use the same `exception` block, but you need to use [RAISE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE). There is no `raise_application_error` function

Comment: yes it's working... thanks for your cooperation... thank you so much

Comment: yes your answer solved my question.. how can i mark this as resolved?